# Regular expression for finding a word

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string

I have a long string of characters as input and I want to count the number of words in that string. How can I do it through regular expression?

Comment: Do you want actual words that make sense in some language or just strings separated with spaces, tabs, new lines and possibly other delimiters?

Comment: `I want to count the number of words` ... does those words have a pattern?

Comment: @Tom The words may or may not make sense.

Comment: @Rahul No they don't follow any specific pattern but they are a part of a paragraph of a book.

Answer (score 2):

You can simple do that (if you do not care for count numbers, and single chars also as words)

```
  int CountOfWords = StringOf.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n' }, 
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
```

Split it to an array, with out count the empty entries, and then get that length. You can define also what you think that is separate your words.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an expression `\w+`, and use regex to enumerate the matches, like this:

```
var s = "Quick brown fox jumps over lazy dog";
foreach (var t in new Regex("\\w+").Matches(s)) {
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can count number of words in string using following code

```
         str = "CSharp split test";
        char[] splitchar = { ' ' };
        strArr = str.Split(splitchar);
        int Count = strArr.Length;
```